# AngularJS function undefined when uncommenting it

Tags: function, angularjs, scope, promise, method-missing

I have some weird problems related with defintion of method inside scope. Once it's defined, and when I want to call it (just by entering it into code) it disappears. I have this part of code

```
if (ConfigurationService.isConfigurationChanged() === true) {
ConfigurationService.getConfiguration().then(function(data) {
    $scope.configuration = data.configuration;
    $scope.lunchers = data.lunchers;

    $scope.configuration.vegies.all_in_one_group = data.configuration.vegies.all_in_one_group;

    var lunchersLength = data.lunchers.all.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < lunchersLength; i++) {
        $scope.selectedVegies[i] = $scope.isVegie(data.lunchers.all[i]);
        $scope.selectedSpecialGroup[i] = $scope.isInSpecialGroup(data.lunchers.all[i]);
        $scope.isAbsent[i] = $scope.isAbsent(data.lunchers.all[i]);
    }   
}); 

} else if (ConfigurationService.isConfigurationChanged() === false)  {

var cached = ConfigurationService.getCachedConfiguration();
console.log($scope.isVegie);
$scope.configuration = cached.configuration;
$scope.lunchers = cached.lunchers;

$scope.configuration.vegies.all_in_one_group = cached.configuration.vegies.all_in_one_group;

var lunchersLength = cached.lunchers.all.length;

for (var j = 0; j < lunchersLength; j++) {
    $scope.selectedVegies[i] = $scope.isVegie(cached.lunchers.all[j]);
    //$scope.selectedSpecialGroup[i] = $scope.isInSpecialGroup(cached.lunchers.all[i]);
    //$scope.isAbsent[i] = $scope.isAbsent(cached.lunchers.all[i]);
}
}
```

Now something weird happens. Can you see:

```
console.log($scope.isVegie);
```

When I have:

```
$scope.selectedVegies[i] = $scope.isVegie(cached.lunchers.all[j]);
```

commented I can see method in firebug, when I uncomment it, it gets undefined...

Anybody had some similar issues?

Note:

```
ConfigurationService.getConfiguration()
```

Is this method:

```
            getConfiguration : function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                    method :'GET',
                    url : "cgi-bin/get_configuration.py"
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (status === 200) {
                        angular.copy(data, configStatus.currentConfig);// = data;
                        configStatus.configurationChanged = false;
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

Comment: where is the `$scope.isVegie();` method?

Comment: In controller where service is called. If first if condition is true then it can find it. In else if part it can't...

And also, weird part is that, when I comment that line:

    $scope.selectedVegies[i] = $scope.isVegie(cached.lunchers.all[j]);

in else condition console.log($scope) will dump correct scope (with isVegie inside), if I remove comment it won't have any of methods...

very weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The thing is that

```
$scope.isVegie
```

was defined after the logic calling it. However, I didn't noticed that when I didn't have else part. When it was without if-else, it was working fine even though method was defined "under" the logic calling it.

This solved the issue.